# Certificar pdf en laravel con certificado .p12

Tags: php, laravel, certificado-ssl, firma-digital

saludos

Tengo el siguiente problema, actualmente necesito certificar un pdf que es enviado mediante un formulario con un certificado de tipo .p12, actualemente este es el siguiente codigo que estoy usando.

```
//Actualmente este lo estoy usando como archivo existente de pruebas, ya que si uso uno directo recibido por formulario me genera otro error
$pdfPath = storage_path('app/public/pZC52BTTVwuDyooQvNLGQwHCFuNfC8jIrFJH9X1S.pdf');


        // Ruta del certificado digital (archivo .pfx o .p12)
        $certPath = storage_path('app/ssl/1F0000198DD148D6DC9D7303CF00000000198D.p12');

        // Contraseña del certificado digital
        $certPass = 'p0gcce0tuwi9';

        // Ruta donde se guardará el archivo firmado
        //$signedPdfPath = 'ruta/donde/guardar/resultado.pdf';

        // Contenido del PDF
        $pdfContent = file_get_contents($pdfPath);

        // Cargar el certificado digital
        $certStore = openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($certPath), $certs, $certPass);

        if (!$certStore) {
            die('Error al cargar el certificado digital.');
        }

        // Extraer la clave privada y el certificado del almacenamiento
        $key = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs['pkey']);
        $cert = openssl_x509_read($certs['cert']);

        // Datos adicionales para la firma
        $extraHeaders = array(
            'Location' => 'Ubicación',
            'Reason' => 'Motivo',
            'ContactInfo' => 'Información de contacto'
        );

        // Firmar el contenido del PDF
        if (openssl_pkcs7_sign($pdfPath, 'providencia.pdf', $cert, $key, null)) {
            echo 'El PDF ha sido firmado correctamente.';
        } else {
            echo 'Error al firmar el PDF.';
        }
```

Aunque este me regresa que fue firmado correctamente, al abrir el archivo generado este me indica que el archivo esta corrupto y no se puede reparar

Comment: Esto creo que te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582054/openssl-pkcs7-sign-error-opening-file